# Use WordPress (PHP) Strings and variables in Svelte

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, svelte

I have an advanced custom configurator for building WooCommerce products.

The jQuery version is extremely slow, old and unoptimized.
I wanted to switch it to Svelte (I know Vue may be a simpler alternative).

I was wondering if it's possible to embed WordPress strings like `<?= __('My text', 'domain'); ?>` in my Svelte code.

Theoretically, it's possible to pass the variables to the JS object, but It's usually extremely tedious and it's simpler to just put the script in a `<script>` section in the PHP file and automatically use the variables echoed there.

Unlike Vue, Svelte compiles to native JS at build-time instead of run-time, so I can't just use the  tag in the file. That's why I was wondering if it's possible to use the WordPress strings in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I develop wordpress plugins using svelte and what you need to do in this case is to path it as global variables to the svelte script using `wp_localize_script` and pass an object of all the data you need there and simply access it using `object.key` .. that's the easiest and recommended way.